# jQuery get checked list ,not checked list and length of checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I don't want to repeat

```
jQuery("#checkboxList input:checkbox:checked").length
jQuery("#checkboxList input:checkbox:checked")
jQuery("#checkboxList input:checkbox:not(:checked)")
```

I want a more elegant solution.Where I can just pass `checked`, `not checked`, `length` params to get the desired result. Like this:

```
var checkboxList = jQuery("#checkboxList input:checkbox");
checkboxList.get(":checked")
checkboxList.get(":not(:checked)")
checkboxList.get(":checked").length
```

```html
<div id="checkboxList">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct method to use is `filter()`, not `get()`:

```js
var $checkboxes = $("#checkboxList input:checkbox");
var $checked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked')
var $unchecked = $checkboxes.filter(':not(:checked)');

console.log('checked', $checked.length);
console.log('unchecked', $unchecked.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checkboxList">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Also note that the number of unchecked can be ascertained from subtracting the number of checked from the total amount of checkboxes. I simply showed both `filter()` statements here for the sake of completeness.